# Some websites are working without Postback browser loading

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I don't know how to explain my question. sorry if i made any wrong.

In web based POS system, whole system is worked like a software means there is no postback loading in browser. when i am using page navigation OR anything else,
there is no browser load. URL was not changing even when i am navigating beween pages. 
I don't think they are using ajax call because POS systems are always huge systems and also not used iframes. they were not used DIV hide show even.

I want to know how they create this kind of websites because i need to create POS system which is not loading at every page event using C# MVC.

Eg, https://wallacepos.com/

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show an example. But regarding to what you say, I think it is Javascript + Ajax.

Comment: https://wallacepos.com/  This is open source POS system. you can see live demo

Comment: https://wallacepos.com/, using ajax calls, you can use developer tool of any browser to check it.

Comment: I just want to confirm that it is just done using ajax calls OR anything else which is out of my knowledge.

Comment: I'll use Jquery ajax call for this.
Thanks @kurdy and RahulR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fully with JavaScript. Please use some js frameworks like ReactJs, AngularJs, BackboneJs etc... you can create nice POS using those.

Comment: You should post this as comment, not answer.

Comment: @M.Kumaran I am too familiar with Jquery ajax calls. so it is okay if i use jquery ajax call in my POS?

Comment: @Bharat It's absolutely OK to use JQuery Ajax